# A change in direction in a corridor (triangle/geometry)

Tags: geometry

Johnny is building a corridor. The corridor is 1.1m wide.

Johnny's corridor is parallel to a wall. Near the end of the corridor the wall turns 90 degrees right for 0.5m, before turning back 90 degrees left. Thus the second part of the wall is parallel to the first, but 0.5m to the right.

See [image: diagram]

Johnny has already cut the wood for the two sections of the corridor, as 1.1m wide rectangles the exact length of the respective walls. Having cut the wood, he has now realised that where the corridor changes direction, it is too narrow, with only 0.6m between the corner of the wall and the edge of the corridor

Johnny wants to cut a right-angled triangle similar to the one highlighted in red which he will add between the two rectangles, so that the corridor is no narrower than 0.9m at any point. What are the minimum dimensions of Johnny's triangle?

Comment: Is that triangular piece of wood going to have one side of 0.6 m? Or could it be shorter?

Comment: it just needs to be the smallest piece of wood that provides 0.9m clearance

Comment: So the triangle doesn't need to fit to the corner of the upper corridor (point $C$ in my figure)?

Comment: Nope, no need to fit into there

Comment: I edited my answer to take that into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the triangular piece of wood (brown in diagram below) have legs of $x$ and $y$ meters, so its hypotenuse is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ meters long. The distance $h$ from the wall corner to the hypotenuse must be $0.9$ m.

The area of the larger yellow+brown triangle can be computed by taking 
$0.6+y$ as base and $x$ as altitude, or the brown triangle hypotenuse as base and $h$ as altitude. By equating these we get the equation:

$$
(0.6+y)\cdot x=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot0.9,
\quad\hbox{whence:}\quad
x={{0.9} y\over \sqrt{y^2 + 1.2 y - 0.45}}.
$$

The area of the brown triangle is then
$$
A={1\over2}xy={0.45 y^2\over \sqrt{y^2 + 1.2 y - 0.45}}.
$$
The minimum can be found by differentiating $A$ with respect to $y$ and equating the result to zero, which leads to the equation:
$$
y^2+1.8y-0.9=0,
\quad\hbox{satisfied by}\quad
y=\sqrt{1.71}-0.9=0.40767.
$$
The corresponding value of $x$ is then $x=0.67043$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean by triangular piece of wood?

[image]

Comment: hi, i've clarified my OP. The triangle needs to fit between the two rectangles, as those are already cut. Your triangle overlaps with the first rectangle

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean to add a triangular piece to the right of the lower corridor and below the upper corridor as shown (in red) in the figure below:

[image]

So if we draw a circle of radius $R=0.9$ with center at the corner of the wall, the triangular piece must cover the part of the circle "sticking out". And pressumably it should connect at point $C$. We can then take the tangent to that circle from $C$ to find points $D$ and $E$.

From $\triangle {AEC}$ we see that $${AE}^2 + {EC}^2 = {AC}^2$$

We know $AE = 0.9$ and $AC=1.1$ which gives $EC =0.63$. We can also see that $\triangle {AEC}$ is similar to $\triangle {DBC}$ which means $$\frac{BC}{EC} = \frac{DC}{AC}$$

which means $$DC =\frac{1.1*0.5}{0.63} =0.87$$

Using Pythagoras we find the last side $BD=0.71$.

Comment: AE = 0.9, but AC doesn't necessarily equal 1.1. 

AC >= 0.9m; there is no need for the triangle to meet at the edge of the upper plan.